# How To Remove Labels From Crystal Reports Pie Chart

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I am fairly new to Crystal Reports and cannot figure out how to remove the labels from a Crystal Reports Pie Chart.  Can someone please tell me what property I need to change to remove the labels from a pie chart?  I have attached a screenshot with an example.  Thanks...

[image: Labels to Remove From Crystal Pie Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the chart and select Chart Expert. Click the Options tab, and then uncheck Show Label. Click OK and that should be it!

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that I overlooked that :-)